# Loop php that prints only the first round a div

Tags: php, mysql, loops

Hello I would like to make this structure a loop. The structure is formed with a query to the database. I have taken many turns to how to perform the loop and can not find the solution.

The structure looks like this:

Example db:

```
id | NombrePelicula | Director | ano | 


1 | Taxi Driver | Martin Scorsesse | 1976

2 | The color of money | Martin Scorsesse | 1986

3 | Spartacus | Stanley Kubrick| 1960

4 | After Hours | Martin Scorsesse | 1985

5 | My name is nobody | Sergio Leone | 1973
```

query:

```
$lista="SELECT * FROM peliculas ORDER BY  id desc";

$listado=mysqli_query($Conex, $lista);



bucle:

while($x=mysqli_fetch_array($listado)){

$id=$x["id"];
$director=$x["director"];
$ano=$x["ano"];
$pelicula=$x["NombrePelicula"];



<div class="director"><span class="director-texto"><?php echo $director?></span></div></div>

echo $pelicula;


}
```

I would like it to appear in this way

```
Martin Scorsse-----------

Taxi Driver

Raging Bull

The Color of Money

Stanley Kubrick------------

Spartacus

Dr. Strangelove

The Shining

Sergio Leone---------

Once Upon a Time in America

A Fistful of Dollars
```

I would do so only makes a query to the database. Without having to make a loop for each director.

What I mean is that for every loop around the director's name and then under his films is printed only once. I have tried to give many laps with conditional but I managed to find the solution

Comment: why are you using `mysqli_fetch_object()`, but accessing them using array keys `$x["id"]`?

Comment: also you have `ORDER BY name`, but I don't see a `name` in your table

Comment: Sorry, I've corrected and edited, you do not want to show my web code and have done something to show you the example. Apologies.

Comment: @chris85 I did not know that function, could make an example with the solution to my problem?

Comment: Okay, posted that as an answer if you have questions please post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this by doing a `ORDER BY director` in your query, and then when looping, check if the current `director` is the same as the last director, and only print the `director` name when it changes -

```
$lista="SELECT * FROM peliculas ORDER BY director";

$listado=mysqli_query($Conex, $lista);

$currentDirector = ""; // simple var to hold current director

while($x=mysqli_fetch_array($listado)){

    $id=$x["id"];
    $director=$x["director"];
    $ano=$x["ano"];
    $pelicula=$x["NombrePelicula"];

    if($director ! = $currentDirector) { // if director not the same as the current director, echo header
    { ?>
        <div class="director"><span class="director-texto"><?php echo $director?></span></div>
    <?php
        $currentDirector = $director; // set this director to current director
    }

    echo $pelicula."<br />";     
}
```

If you want to wrap the director and movies in a `<div>` you would do something like this

```
$lista="SELECT * FROM peliculas ORDER BY director";

$listado=mysqli_query($Conex, $lista);

$currentDirector = ""; // simple var to hold current director

while($x=mysqli_fetch_array($listado)){

    $id=$x["id"];
    $director=$x["director"];
    $ano=$x["ano"];
    $pelicula=$x["NombrePelicula"];

    if($director ! = $currentDirector) { // if director not the same as the current director, echo header
    { 
        if($currentDirector != "") { // if not the 1st director, close the last director div before we open a new director div
            echo "</div>"; // closes last div
        }
    ?>
        <div class="director"><span class="director-texto"><?php echo $director?></span><br />
    <?php
        $currentDirector = $director; // set this director to current director
    }

    echo $pelicula."<br />";     
}
echo "</div>"; // close the last director div
```

Comment: Great, just great. Thank you very much, I never had happened

Comment: Sean, a new question has arisen me, what if I want the list of films which is under the director is included in full in a div?

The problem is that each film within a div is inserted, and I like that they are all stuck in a div container. Thank you.

Comment: So you want a `<div>` to wrap around the director name and all its movie titles?

Comment: I have updated my answer with a way to have the `<div class="director">` to wrap around all the director's movies as well.

Comment: Great, fantastic, sensational !! Thank you !!

Answer (score 2):

Use `group by` and [group_concat](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) to get all the movies each director did in one row.

```
select director, group_concat(movie) 
from movies
group by director
```

Then you can just explode the movie row on `,`s or string replace the comma to a newline.

SQL Fiddle example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a0d32/2

`Str_replace` example:

```
$string = 'Taxi Driver,The color of money,After Hours';
echo str_replace(',', '<br>', $string);
```

Output:

```
Taxi Driver<br>The color of money<br>After Hours
```

PHP Demo: https://eval.in/476090

or as a full example with your code (untested)...

```
<?php
$lista="SELECT director, group_concat(NombrePelicula) as movie FROM peliculas group by director ORDER BY director";
$listado=mysqli_query($Conex, $lista);
$currentDirector = ""; // simple var to hold current director
while($x=mysqli_fetch_array($listado)){
    $director=$x["director"];
    $pelicula=$x["movie"];
?>
    <div class="director"><span class="director-texto"><?php echo $director?></span></div>
<?php
    echo str_replace(',', '<br>', $pelicula);     
}
?>
```

Comment: this is a great alternative, but just beware of [`group_concat_max_len`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_group_concat_max_len) which is default at `1024` bytes. Most directors will probably be fine, although `Martin Scorsese` may be close - http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0000217/

Comment: Thanks, wasn't aware of that setting.

Comment: Thank you very much, I will point me your solution that is also of great value. Greetings friend

Comment: I can not score, I have enough points to do so. I feel bad because I would like to thank you.

Comment: No problem, maybe if you get that privilege in the future and remember you can come back.

Comment: Thank you very much, rest assured that I will.